# Verilog Syntax Error?

Tags: syntax, verilog

I am trying to implement a CounterMod7 with Stop input to freeze the output value while `Stop = 1`.

I just can't for the life of me figure out why I'm getting the message `Syntax error near ')'`, pointing to the line just above `end` in the code below:

```
module CounterMod7Reset(
  input clock,
  input reset,
  input Stop,
  output reg[2:0] value
);

  always @(posedge clock) begin
    value <= (!Stop ||(Stop && reset)) ? 
             (reset ? 0 : value == 3'b110 ? 0 : (value + 1)) : 
             (Stop ? (value + 0));
  end
endmodule
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A classic example of why nested ternary operators are generally frowned upon ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know this language, but I do know this: every expression needs something to return. Therefore, the ternairy operator `?:` needs a `:`, an else. So I think you get the error because you don't have an else case in your last ternairy operator (marked with `???`):

```
always @(posedge clock) begin
            value <= (!Stop ||(Stop && reset))
            ? (reset
              ? 0
              : value == 3'b110 ? 0
                                : (value + 1))
            : (Stop
              ? (value + 0)
              : ???);
end
```

I tried to change indentation to make clear the structure.

Answer (score 0):

It look s like a case statement might be easier to understand, some thing like:

```
wire max = (value == 3'b110);
always @(posedge clock) begin
 casez ({stop,reset, max})
   ?1? : value <= 'b0;
   000 : value <= value + 1;
   100 : value <= value;
end
```

But an if else would be more typical for encoding the reset condition:

```
always @(posedge clock) begin
 if (reset) begin
   value <= 'b0;
 end
 else if (!stop & (value < 3'b110)) begin
   value <= value + 1
 end
end
```

Comment: I think he wants the counter to roll over at 7, not freeze, so you need a separate case of that: `else if (!stop) begin if (value < 3'b110) value <= value + 3'b1; else value <= 3'b0; end` or something like that.